# Matlab-Arduino serial data baudrate v/s sample numbers

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino-uno

I made a ppg sensor and acquiring the data from it to my laptop via Matlab - Arduino Uno interface.

I had been changing the baud rate in the arduino code available from mathworks package and also the corresponding matlab code. I made the following observation:

Baud-Rate         Samples/sec

1200                 6
2400                12
4800                24
9600                30
38400               30
115200              30

So what I observe is the saturation in number of samples/sec from 9600 and later.

Suggestions regarding this are requested.

Thanks.

Comment: You mention what you observe, but what is the specific problem you would like to improve? Do you wish just to hear some more aspects? Are some rates missing below 9600? Could a code snippet help to understand the problem?

Comment: Hi,

I just found that Arduino-Uno supports only till 9600 BR. So its fine I cant expect more no. of samples beyond it using this. 

I need a sampling rate of 250 samples/sec or more. Any suggestions @peter

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to know? If my answer doesn't fit your question please tell me.

`Arduino Uno` can only support up to 9600. If you want a faster speed you can use `Arduino Mega` at a speed of *57600*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I'll look into Arduino Mega for higher BR.

The thing is if Uno supports till 9600 then I need to observe a proportionate increase in number of samples from i.e 9600 BR to give 48 Sp/sec following the trend from 1200 BR.